# Display the result with not null value first then with null value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with list of all country names along with amount field. What I need is to display the country name with amount not equal to 0 at top order in ascending order of name and then display the country with amount value 0.

```
Name          Amount
Afghanistan    0
Argentina      0
China          0.1
Crotia         0
Hongkong       0.08
India          0.2
Singapore      0.007
Taiwan         0.22
```

Required Output:

```
Name          Amount
China          0.1
Hongkong       0.08
India          0.2
Singapore      0.007
Taiwan         0.22
Afghanistan    0
Argentina      0
Crotia         0
```

I have tried following till now but its not working.

```
select * from countries where amount !=0 ORDER by name ASC 
UNION ALL
SELECT * from countries where amount == 0 ORDER BY name ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM countries
  ORDER BY (Amount=0), Name
```

Comment: Up voted. The result is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can order by a custom `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM countries
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,    -- places zeroes last
    amount                                     -- then order by the amount
```

Comment: This would order by amount, but I believe based on the output given by the thread starter he wanted the result to be ordered by name with amount > 0 and place those with 0 amount at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think mysql treats 0 as null. Typically null always returns false with any comparison, so instead of checking if  the value is 0 check if its not null. So select * from countries where amount is not null order by name asc union all select * from countries where amount is null

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like?

```
SELECT * FROM countries 
ORDER BY 
CONCAT(CASE amount WHEN 0 THEN "Z" ELSE "A" END,`name`) asc;
```